# Does .Net 4.5.2 framework supports Samesite cookies with URL Rewrite

Tags: security, cookies, csrf, samesite

We are using .Net 4.5.2 and trying to add SameSite=Lax cookie attribute using URL rewrite rule. But getting Service Unavailable error. Does .Net 4.5.2 supports this?

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation you can find that SameSite attribute is handled in .NET 4.7.2 and 4.8: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/samesite/system-web-samesite).

When you use web.config with lower version, VisualStudio underlines the SameSite attribute in Web.config and says SameSite is not allowed. There is also no SameSite and Secure properties for Cookie object until version 4.7.2.

I tried to run page with SameSite attributes with .NET 4.7.1 application and that worked, the app was able to run. I haven't checked if SameSite attribute in request is understood by server, but I know that SameSite attribute is present in Set-Cookie response header (.NET patch caused that).

You are probably missing .NET framework patch which adds such functionality. As I can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/samesite/kbs-samesite), there are only patches for .NET from version 4.6 to 4.8, so unfortunately there is no patch for .NET 4.5.2.

> Does .Net 4.5.2 supports this?

**It does not**.You first have to upgrade your .NET version to at least 4.6.

(My first answer on SO )